# Drupal wont change the temporary file path in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I am facing a weird problem. I keep getting error messages on my drupal site by just visiting a node:

> The specified file temporary://filezATB93 could not be copied, because
>   the destination directory is not properly configured. This may be
>   caused by a problem with file or directory permissions. More
>   information is available in the system log.

but all the dirs exist and have 777 permissions. I changed the temp dir from `/tmp` to `tmp` in the admin config but after visiting the website it switched back to `/tmp` again, so I put this in the `settings.php`:

```
$conf['file_temporary_path'] = 'tmp';
```

But both the `/tmp` and `tmp` have 777 permission. The weird thing is, when I export the database the table `variable` has the value pair `temporary_file_path` and it is always set to `"/tmp"`, even if I drop the table and insert `"tmp"` right after that, every time the db exports `"/tmp"`. How can I change this?

Comment: "because the **destination directory** is not properly configured"...check permissions on /sites/default/files or equivalent, not the temp folder

Comment: clive, i figured it out, it is as you said the files folder, more specific the languages folder. post the answer and ill accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be a bit confusing, but the **destination directory** there refers to a path under Drupal's public file system, not the temp folder (which is the *source* in this case).

If you [update permissions](https://drupal.org/node/244924) on the files folder, usually DRUPAL_ROOT/sites/all/default, the problem should disappear.